# EF Code First - Map Dictionary or custom type as an nvarchar

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to use EF Code first for a database that I'm currently accessing using plain old ADO.NET with stored procedures.

In my database I have some `nvarchar(MAX)` columns that should be mapped to and from a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

When saved to database, it is an XML formatted string. I use this technique to allow internationalization of e.g. a name of a product in an online store. I don't know how many languages any given user want to translate to so I can't have a `Name` column for each language.

I also wanted to avoid storing the values in a seperate table, so I ended up with the Dictionary - XML approach.

The way I do it now, is to just treat any of these columns as a string whenever I interact with the database. I have a custom mapper function that can turn the XML into a Dictionary, and back to XML.

But I can't seem to find a way to do this with EF Code first? Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

You can add a property that will return your `Dictionary<,>` as a XML string and then remove the mapping for your `Dictionary<,>` property.

```
    [NotMapped]
    public Dictionary<string,string> MyDictionary
    {
     get; set;
    }

    public string DictionaryAsXml
    {
        get
        {
             return ToXml(MyDictionary);
        }
        set
        {
           MyDictionary = FromXml(value);
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to expose your `DictionaryAsXml` property have a look at [this blog post](http://blog.cincura.net/232147-mapping-private-or-protected-properties-with-code-first-efv4-ctp4/). It shows how you can persist private and protected properties.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :) -- I would not have thought to do that

Comment: Why XML and not JSON, the last is more compact and would be more efficient in term of DB storage no ?

Comment: @Piou I can't remember exactly what I was thinking five years ago but I guess I was still more used to XML then to JSON. I do assume the example would also work with JSON so feel free to try it. Remember however that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Because SQL Server can query against XML -- it's not fast, but it's built-in. -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also you might benefit from setting these properties to `[StringLength(int.MaxValue)]` so that you don't run into column size issues.

Comment: WHOA! -- It looks like, as of SQL Server 2016 (and Azure SQL), you can now query against JSON data as well! -- And the support for JSON looks to be stronger than that of XML (e.g. you can convert JSON to and from datasets which you can perform selects on, etc.)  -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

I had some difficulties with the xml conversion in VB.NET. Therefore I took advantage of newtonsoft.json to serialize the dictionary to a JSON string and back.

```
Public Property JsonDict As String
    Get
        If MyDict Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyDict)
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        If value Is Nothing Then
            MyDict = Nothing
        Else
            MyDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of Single, Single))(value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
<NotMapped>
Public Property MyDict As Dictionary(Of Single, Single)
```