# MVC 4 - Dictionary not saved

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've added some Dictionaries to the entity "portfolio". The values therein are not updated directly by the user, rather the entity itself has a method to fill / refresh this dictionary.

I'm calling this refresh method from another Controller, right before the return action:

```
..
portfolio.refreshDicts();
db.SaveChanges();
```

By debugging, I can see that refreshDicts() adds 6 values to the dict, just as it should. But these are not getting stored, though calling db.SaveChanges() ... When I try to access a dict in another controller, I can see that it is empty.

I'm performing another operation on portfolio in the same Controller method just some steps before trying to call refreshDicts() (adding an object to a list in portfolio) and this is saved correctly.

**How can that be? Thank you for your help!**

**Update**

**Class Portfolio with the Dictionaries**

```
public class Portfolio
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GroupID { get; set; }

    public virtual List<KassenwirksamesEreignis> KassenwirksameEreignisse { get; set; }
    public virtual List<InternMsg> InterneNachrichten { get; set; }
    public virtual List<StockPosition> StockPositions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<BondPosition> BondPositions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FuturePosition> FuturePositions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OptionPosition> OptionPositions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FondsPosition> FondsPositions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Regelereignis> RegelEreignisse { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> FondsVolumenDict { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> KasseDict { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> StockDict { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> OptionDict { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> FutureDict { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> FondsDict { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, double> BondDict { get; set; }

    public Portfolio()
    {
        FondsVolumenDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
        KasseDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
        StockDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
        OptionDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
        FutureDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
        FondsDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
        BondDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>();
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
   public ActionResult Create(StockPosition position)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // find user's portfolio
            string currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
            string userGroupId = db.UserProfiles.Single(x => x.UserName == currentUser).GroupId;
            Portfolio portfolio = db.Portfolios.Single(x => x.GroupID == userGroupId);

            // add Stock to portfolio
            position.PortfolioID = portfolio.ID;
            db.StockPositions.Add(position);

            // book costs 
            var ke = new KassenwirksamesEreignis();
            ke.Art = "Kauf";
            ke.Bezeichnung = position.Bezeichnung;
            ke.Date = DateTime.Now;
            ke.Wert = Math.Round((-1.0) * (position.Menge * position.Kaufpreis), 2);
            portfolio.KassenwirksameEreignisse.Add(ke);

            // Dictionaries refreshen
            portfolio.refreshDicts();
            db.Entry(portfolio).State = EntityState.Modified;

            // Save & Back
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../Portfolio/Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("../Portfolio/Index");
    }
```

**my Context:**

```
public class PlanspielContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GlobalMsg> GlobalNachrichten { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InternMsg> InterneNachrichten { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Price> Prices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KassenwirksamesEreignis> KassenwirksameEreignisse { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Zinsanspruch> Zinsansprüche { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StockPosition> StockPositions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OptionPosition> OptionPositions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FuturePosition> FuturePositions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BondPosition> BondPositions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FondsPosition> FondsPositions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Regelereignis> Regelereignisse { get; set; }

    // Am not sure if i need those here .. ?
    //public Dictionary<DateTime, double> FondsVolumenDict { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<DateTime, double> KasseDict { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<DateTime, double> StockDict { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<DateTime, double> OptionDict { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<DateTime, double> FutureDict { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<DateTime, double> FondsDict { get; set; }
    //public Dictionary<DateTime, double> BondDict { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }   
}
```

**the refreshDict method i'm calling**

```
    public void refreshDicts()
    {
        refreshBondDict();
        refreshFondsDict();
        refreshFutureDict();
        refreshOptionDict();
        refreshStockDict();
        refreshKasseDict();
        refreshFondsVolumenDict();
    }

    public void refreshFondsDict()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

        for ( var i = - 4; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            DateTime currentDay = today.AddDays(i).Date;

            if (this.FondsDict.ContainsKey(currentDay))
            {
                this.FondsDict[currentDay] = getFondsValue(currentDay);
            }
            else
            {
                this.FondsDict.Add(currentDay, getFondsValue(currentDay));
            }
        }
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying to the framework that you modified the entity:

```
..
portfolio.refreshDicts();
db.Entry(portfolio).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

### Edit

After seeing the updated code, it looks like you are trying to save the `Dictionary` objects directly to the database. It is not possible to map a `Dictionary` to a database table with Entity Framework. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9775394/2021517).

Comment: Thank you for your tip, unfortunatly it's still not being saved. Please see my updated question, I have added code from my context and the controller.. Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to save the Dictionaries directly to the database. This [is not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9775394/2021517). I updated the answer and the linked answer has some suggestions for how to deal with Dictionaries.

Comment: Doh! Thanks you for that, shame on me I had not found that question.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For what you have written i think you have 2 different Objects of typeof(db). That is to say you have 2 `dbContexts` and you are adding objects to one and saving the other.

By default `dbContexts` track the entities and hance if you call save from another the added entities are not tracked by this instance and therefore are not saved. 
call `.SaveChanges()` on the context in which your are making changes and everything should work fine

UPDATE:-
there is some problem with your code. The Dictionary Items cannot be stores directly in the database. instead try adding the items to a table or to a DbSet

Comment: I get a reference to portfolio like this: Portfolio portfolio = db.Portfolios.Single(x => x.GroupID == userGroupId); where "db" is the only reference to my context. So is should be only one Object of typof(db), or am I missing something here ??

Comment: Oh and in the other controller where I'm trying to access the dict, I'm using private myContext db = new myContext(); , just as I do in the controller where "refreshDicts()" is called..

Comment: Parv, can you please have a look at the code I've added. I would be very thankfull to know why changes are not being saved!!

Comment: in the ques you wrote down that you are call refreshDicts function right before the return action.. where is that code?

Comment: See the Controller part of the code:                          // Dictionaries refreshen
            portfolio.refreshDicts();
            db.Entry(portfolio).State = EntityState.Modified;

            // Save & Back
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../Portfolio/Index");